# Using AyncTask to send a UDP packet

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, udp

I am trying to send a UDP packet to a computer on the same network as my tablet. In order to do this, I began by setting up a class to hold all the appropriate objects that I need in order to create a UDP socket, create a packet, and then send that packet. This class is shown below:

```
public static class Session
    {
        public InetAddress address;
        public DatagramSocket socket;
        public DatagramPacket packet;
        public String client;
        public int port;
        public byte[] receive_buffer;
        public byte[] send_buffer;
        public String message;

        public Session (InetAddress address, DatagramSocket socket, DatagramPacket packet,
                        String client, int port, byte[] receive_buffer, byte[] send_buffer,
                        String message)
        {
            this.address = address;
            this.socket = socket;
            this.packet = packet;
            this.client = client;
            this.receive_buffer = receive_buffer;
            this.send_buffer = send_buffer;
            this.message = message;
            this.port = port;
        }
    }
```

Whenever I try to send a UDP packet, I begin by creating a Session object that contains a socket, packet, message, and a few other things. I also have a Send class that I use to actually send the UDP packet. This is shown below:

```
public static Session Send (Session session)
    {
        // Execute within "try" function to catch exceptions
        try
        {
            /* Create address*/
            session.address = InetAddress.getByName(session.client);
            /* Create socket */
            session.socket = new DatagramSocket(session.port);
            /* Create packet */
            session.packet = new DatagramPacket(session.message.getBytes(),
                                 session.message.length(), session.address, session.port);
            /* Send packet */
            session.socket.send(session.packet);
            /* Return session */
            return session;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("MYAPP", "exception: " + e.getMessage());
            Log.e("MYAPP", "exception: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

However, Send() cannot be called directly, since one cannot perform network operations on the UI thread. In order to remedy this, I created an AsyncTask that calls Send(). Now all I have to do is pass the Session object to the AsyncTask and it will send the packet (in theory). The AsyncTask that I created is shown below:

```
class sendData extends AsyncTask<UDP.Session, Void, UDP.Session>
    {

        /* Pre-Execute Function */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute ()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        /* Main AsyncTask Function */
        @Override
        protected UDP.Session doInBackground(UDP.Session... arguments)
        {
            /* Send UDP packet */
            UDP.Session session = UDP.Send(arguments[0]);
            return session;
        }

        /* Post-Execute Function */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (UDP.Session session)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(session);
        }
    }
```

The issue that I am experiencing is that I cannot figure out how to return the session object from my AsyncTask. It is critical that I return the session that I passed to the AsyncTask, because otherwise the socket/port becomes corrupted and I get binding exceptions and a whole bunch of other issues when I try to send another packet. I tried using:

```
UDP.Session nsession = new sendData().execute(ssession).get();
```

but I get an error that states "Unhandled exceptions: java.lang.InterruptedException, java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException". So my question is what is the best way for me to return the session object that I pass to the AsyncTask so that I can use that same session object next time I want to send a packet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was being silly and not paying attention to the compiler warnings about the unhandled exceptions. The AsyncTask call made above (`UDP.Session nsession = new sendData().execute(ssession).get();`) is indeed correct, but it just needs to be placed inside a try/catch statement catch any possible exceptions. When I changed my code to the following...

```
try{
    session = new sendData().execute(session).get();}
catch (Exception exception){}
```

...everything worked. I am able to properly return an object from the AsyncTask, and my socket no longer gets corrupted when the AsyncTask finished, allowing me to send as many packets as I want